# Meaning of notation $\{0,1/2,1\}^V$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, optimization, notation

In the context of studying a polyhedral search space I am asked to prove that the set of extremal points is a subset of $\{0,1/2,1\}^V$?

I do vaguely remember having seen this before, in algebra, where it was related to some kind of dual space and something to do with homomorphisms. Can anyone help?

Comment: In elementary set theory if $X$ and $Y$ are (nonempty) sets then $X^Y$ denotes the set of functions from $Y$ to $X$.

Comment: What is $V$? If we're talking extremal *points*, I'd expect the notation to mean the set of all $V$-dimensional points whose coordinates are taken from $\{0, 1/2, 1\}$.

Comment: In this case V is a vertex set. I am trying to approximate the weighted vertex cover problem for planar graphs. (Like the set cover problem)